# jQuery doesn't fire $.ajax.fail() when Mockjax returns status:500 (or 400 or...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mockjax

Mockjax setup:

```
$.mockjax({
  url: "/api/get",
  responseTime: 100, // default: 500
  dataType: "json",
  data: { action: "all" },
  proxy: "data.json",
  status: 400
});
```

The call to mockjax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/get',
  dataType: "json",
  data: { action: "all" }
})
.always(function() {
  //something
})
.done(function(json) {
  console.log("done");
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("error");
});
```

The mockjax properly returns the (JSON) data, but **the problem is** that always the `done()` callback is called (and never the `fail()`), regardless of mockjax status number set.

But if I intentionally set the bad proxy path, only then the `fail()` is fired.

What gives?

Comment: It seems like a bug with mockjax.  You should file a bug.  For the time being, you could pipe the results through a `.then()` and have that fail when it sees a status other than 2xx.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have posted an issue on mockjax github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed in Mockjax v1.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Until [the mockjax issue](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/issues/117) is resolved, here are (some) workarounds that fire `$.ajax.fail()` callback:

- `isTimeout: true`
- malformed `proxy:` path